# Как передать параметры из HTML в RequestBody?

Tags: html, json, spring, freemarker

Есть метод в контроллере:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/{movieId}/session")
    public String addSession(@PathVariable Long movieId, @RequestBody @Valid AddTimeOfSessionRequest request) {
            Long id = new AddTimeOfSession(movieSessionService.addTimeOfSession(request)).getTimeOfSessionId();
            return "redirect:/gateway-api/api/movies/" + movieId;
        }
```

т.е. в данный метод поступает json с несколькими полями:

```
public class AddTimeOfSessionRequest {

private final String timeOfSession;
private final Long movieId;
private final int price;
private final Long hallId;

public AddTimeOfSessionRequest(
        @JsonProperty("timeOfSession") String timeOfSession,
        @JsonProperty("movieId") Long movieId,
        @JsonProperty("price") int price,
        @JsonProperty("hallId") Long hallId) {
    this.timeOfSession = timeOfSession;
    this.movieId = movieId;
    this.price = price;
    this.hallId = hallId;
// get методы
}
```

и вопрос, как из формы передать JSON, который бы соответствовал этому классу?
допустим форма выглядит так:

```html
<form method="post">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" id="timeOfSession" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="введите время сеанса"/>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" id="movieId" value="${movieId}" />

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" id="price" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="введите стоимость билета на сеанс"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <#list cinemaHalls as cinemaHall>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="hallId" name="hallId" value="${cinemaHall.getHallId()}">
                    <p class="lead">${cinemaHall.getName()}</p>
            </#list>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Добавить</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

если каждый параметр передавать через @RequestParam, то все норм. но хочется сделать код компактнее, поэтому вынес в отдельный класс.

Answer (score 0):

убрал аннотацию @RequestBody и все заработало. в форме json-поля(имена) передаются по name, а не по id. Если кто-то объяснит как работать с @RequestBody, то буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте атрибут **id** тега **input** заменить на атрибут **name** и работать через @RequestBody